# Eisenstein series estimate from Stein-Shakarchi's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I need help with this exercise from [Stein-Shakarchi's Complex Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/7563.html) (page 280), Chapter 9 (An Introduction to Elliptic Functions), Exercise 8

> Let $$E_{4}(\tau)=\sum_{(n,m)\neq (0,0)}{\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^{4}}}$$
>   be the Eisenstein series of order $4$. Show that
>   $$\left|E_{4}(\tau)-\frac{\pi^{4}}{45}\right|\leq c e^{-2\pi t}\ \text{if}\ \tau = x + it\ \text{and}\ t \geq 1.$$
>   and deduce that
>   $$\left|E_{4}(\tau)-\tau^{-4}\frac{\pi^{4}}{45}\right|\leq c t^{-4} e^{-2\pi/ t}\ \text{if}\ \tau = it\  \text{and}\  0 < t \leq 1.$$

My idea is to use the estimates from the proof of Theorem 2.5 of pp. 277, but I can't see a finish.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: On page 277, we have the information that in general
$$E_{k}(\tau)=\sum_{(n,m)\neq (0,0)}{\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^{k}}} = 2 \zeta(k) + \frac{2 (-1)^{k/2} (2 \pi)^{k} }{(k-1)!} \sum_{m >0 } {\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}{l^{k-1}e^{2\pi i \tau m l }}}.$$

Comment: You might better your chances of getting help if you mention what the estimates on pg. 277 are.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not so bad as I thought. I actually managed to do it by using the crude estimate $\sigma_{3}(r) \leq r^{4} \leq e ^{2\pi t r}$ for $t \geq 1$ (the first part); as for the second part, it is just a matter of tricking it using the first estimate using the inversion formula for $E_{k}(\tau)$.